# can't access json object returned from express get route in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, express

I have an express route that returns the following JSON

```
[{"_id":"573da7305af4c74002790733","postcode":"nr22ry","firstlineofaddress":"20 high house avenue","tenancynumber":"12454663","role":"operative","association":"company","hash":"b6ba35492f3f83a79395386cfc601178dfd11de723d2007daf6bd34160a9ff16c87b1f07835e7a39c20454c6271960930211b365ae05c620809c159a3d7b97de","salt":"8d544f21c436494da859cf5895c414d9","username":"yhy","__v":0}]
```

In my angular app i have a factory with the following code

```
auth.userRole = function() {
   alert('here');
   if (auth.isLoggedIn()){
          return $http.get('/roles/' + auth.currentUser(), {
headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
  }).then(function(response){          
    //the info is here, i just can't get to it!!!

    return response;          
  });   
   }
};
```

that is called in my controller

```
$scope.therole = auth.userRole();
```

In my view i have

#### user role is: {{ therole }}

My problem is that whilst when i debug (using chrome) my angular, is can see that response has the json in it (see below),  i can't access it! I've tried different permutations of returning response.data or response.data.role or response.role or response[0].role, etc etc, none of these work either return blank or causing a 'property not defined error'.
This should be straightforward so i'm obviously doing something really stupid. Please help!

```
Object
config
:
Object
data
:
Array[1]
0
:
Object
__v
:
0
_id
:
"573da7305af4c74002790733"
association
:
"company"
firstlineofaddress
:
"20 high house avenue"
hash
:
 "b6ba35492f3f83a79395386cfc601178dfd11de723d2007daf6bd34160a9ff16c87b1f07835e7a39c20454c6271960930211b365ae05c620809c159a3d7b97de"
postcode
:
"nr22ry"
role
:
"operative"
salt
:
"8d544f21c436494da859cf5895c414d9"
tenancynumber
:
"12454663"
username
:
"yhy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve my own issue with the following:

```
   auth.theUserInfo = function() {
   if (auth.isLoggedIn()){
          return $http.get('/roles/' + auth.currentUser(), {
headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
 }).then(function(response){          
    //the info is here, i just can't get to it!!!

    return response.data[0];
  });   
   }
};
```

the response.data[0] returns the whole object.

I then realised my real problem was in my controller, i was just assuming by assigning the return value of the function to a variable that it would pass the value back, but i forgot its all async so i can't assume that the function will have got the result by the time it assigns the return value to the variable.
So i changed the code to this

```
auth.theUserInfo().then(function(data) {
   $scope.therole = data.role; 

});
```

this now works!. plus as my (now renamed) theUserInfo function now returns the whole object not just the role, i can potentially re-use it elsewhere in my controller.